# Crazy and difficult Limits and integration

Tags: integration, limits

This limit take from me much time to solve and finally I can't.  So please help me to solve.. 
Find  $L$
$ L =\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x} t^{t-1} ( t + tln (t) +1 ) dt }{x^x} =?  $

Comment: Writing $x^x = e^{xln(x)}$ it is easy to differentiate, so L'Hopital's rule should work, no?

Comment: What about integration ???

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: The posted solution below correctly differentiates numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 2):

Without using l'Hôpital, you may simply remark that for $x \to +\infty$
$$
\int_1^x t^{t-1} (t+t\ln t + 1)dt \sim \int_1^x t^t(1+\ln t)dt = x^x - 1 \sim x^x
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Our limit is 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{x-1}(x(1+\ln x)+1)}{x^x(1+\ln x)}.$$
Observe the cancellations.